# site-wide variables from database

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to set some variables for my whole Rails App to use them in controllers and actions.

These variables should set before all actions and taken from the **database**.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: variables stored in database? bad IMO

Comment: yes, variables are in database

Comment: @AndreyDeineko: hm? Why do you think so?

Comment: @Gediminas: the best way would be to load them from the database in a `before_action`. What's the question here, again?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I think so because my understanding of variable is that it is something you define in class/module/action wherever, not in database. Why would anyone store settings in database instead of, well, settings? But it's my vision, I am not a seasoned developer, but never saw the practice of storing variables in database.

Comment: @AndreyDeineko: what do you mean by "instead of, well, settings"? What is this settings storage? Hardcoded values in the code? This may not be desired for many reasons.

Comment: @AndreyDeineko: fetching app-wide settings from database is very useful in, say, multi-tenant apps.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev yes, I meant hardcoded stuff in some file, that file may not be put into version control for security reasons, but loaded in runtime from server. But I'll read about the practice of storing settings in db.

Comment: in my app variables are changed on the go, depends on subdomain and url  patterns... and values of them can be changed dynamically...

Comment: @AndreyDeineko: also, storing stuff in a database allows you to adjust behaviour of the app without deploy. Say, tune interval that your app uses for shortpolling ( change from 1 sec to 3 secs, or something). Many applications here :)

Comment: @AndreyDeineko: feature toggling!

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Ok, deploy-related thing makes a lot of sense. Thanks for examples!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A before action in your `ApplicationController` can set the variables.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController
  before_action :set_variables # before_actions in ApplicationController always come first

  def set_variables
    @variable1 = Model.find(x).value  # Will be available everywhere for the life of the request
  ...
```

But could you provide a little more context as this may not be the right approach. These might be better as constants defined in environment files, depending on the requirements.

Comment: thanks for the answer. It works in my development, but not in production. In production @variable1 is nil. Can't understand why. For test į just set `@variable1=1` on application_controller... This was the reason why I asked the question to be sure going on the right path and now confirmed with this still handling this error :))

Comment: That would suggest your database is missing the relevant value.

Comment: for the test I'm not using it. Just manually defined `@variable1 = 1`

Comment: Post all the relevant code and we'll try to work out why.